# Alpine Linux - How to prevent .ash_history from being saved?

Tags: history, alpine-linux

How can one prevent `.ash_history` from being saved at all in Alpine Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
unset HISTFILE
```

To make the change permanent, add it to your profile. It should be /etc/profile or ~/.profile

Comment: This no longer works, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667842/alpine-linux-how-to-prevent-ash-history-from-being-saved/762506#762506) for alternatives and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to ~/.profile (or /etc/profile to disable history for all users):

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

Alternatively, run the following command:

```
rm ~/.ash_history; ln -s /dev/null ~/.ash_history
```

(This replaces ~/.ash_history with a symlink pointing to [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), so that writes to ~/.ash_history will be discarded. To re-enable history, remove ~/.ash_history.)

---

Note that `unset HISTFILE` (which is commonly used with bash) doesn't work for two reasons:

- Since Busybox 1.22 (released January 2014; [commit](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/shell/ash.c?h=aeb717aa5e8a)), ash sources ~/.profile *before* it sets HISTFILE, to allow ~/.profile to change HOME. An unfortunate side effect is that unsetting HISTFILE in ~/.profile has no effect.
- Even before that, it only worked when ash was invoked as a login shell, because non-login shells (e.g. those started by running `ash` or by GNU screen) don't source ~/.profile so they would save history. (The first command I suggest uses `export` to ensure that all child processes will inherit the setting.)